# Homebrew?? error: option --no-user-cfg not recognized

Tags: python, homebrew

Using homebrew, in which I am have no skill, I was updating cmake (as part of install of avidemux...) on snow leopard

```
 $brew -v upgrade cmake
```

Everything works fine through

```
Verifying cmake--markupsafe-0.23.tar.gz checksum
```

then I get an error after the following line:

```
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/private/tmp/cmake-lwlJTD/cmake-3.1.0/sphinx --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: option --no-user-cfg not recognized
```

Unfortunately, as you see, it appears some of the command is ellipsed, so I don't quite know to what the --no-user-config is an option. A Google search gave all kinds of irrelevant results.

I thought it was a problem with python:

```
$brew -v upgrade python
Homebrew 0.9.5
Error: python 2.7.9 already installed
Kernel.exit
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Appendix:
some output from the verbose listing that I have no clue about.

```
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 8879b432be43507f2178cfe1628edc5f48554d42
Last commit: 56 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.6.8-i386
Xcode: 3.2.6
CLT: N/A
GCC-4.0: build 5494
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM-GCC: build 2335
Clang: 1.7 build 77
MacPorts/Fink: /opt/local/bin/port
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-p358
Perl: /opt/local/bin/perl => /opt/local/bin/perl5.12
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
Java: 1.6.0_65
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: gcc-4.2
HOMEBREW_CXX: g++-4.2
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.6
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/3.2.6:/usr/local/opt/xz/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Error: cmake 3.1.0 did not build
Logs:
     /Users/myname/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cmake/01.python

These open issues may also help:
cmake reports: CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!! (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35888)
cmake 3.1.1 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/36151)
cmake builds fail on CLT-only with --env=std (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29101)

ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/ctest ctest
ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cpack cpack
ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmakexbuild cmakexbuild
ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/cmake cmake
ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/bin/ccmake ccmake
ln -s ../../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/doc/cmake cmake
ln -s ../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/cmake cmake
ln -s ../../Cellar/cmake/3.0.0/share/aclocal/cmake.m4 cmake.m4
```

Comment: Neither [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/install.html) nor [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) seem the culprit ( I searched through the `git` resp. `mercurial` history of those projects for "`user-cfg`")

Comment: curiouser and curiouser, said alice.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install cmake --without-docs
```

This did the trick for me. The options for building a specific brew package are shown by running `brew options <package>`:

```
brew options cmake
```